# Android: How can I access the default text color? (No theme, just the standard one)

Tags: android, user-interface, textcolor

very short question: if I want to set some text (in a TextView) back to the default text color, how can I do this?

I'm not using any themes.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I used the following way: At the initialization I backuped the default color and when I had to reset I just used the stores value.

Comment: Did you use "TextView.getTextColors().getColorForState(stateSet, defaultColor)" or "TextView.getTextColor(Context context, TypedArray attrs, int def)" ?

Comment: ah, forget it, found TextView.getTextColors().getDefaultColor(). :) Thank you very much!

Comment: Hey jellyfish, Can you post code of TextView.getTextColors().getDefaultColor() I cann't understand how to use it. Actually I want to apply default textcolor in all my activity. Thanks.

Answer (score 15):

I used the solution from jellyfish's comment on the first answer.  A lot of code for something so simple as removing color. To make it clear:

```
private TextView myTextView;
private int defaultTextColor;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    myTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.myTextView);
    defaultTextColor = myTextView.getTextColors().getDefaultColor();
}

public void changeColorBack() {
    myTextView.setTextColor(defaultTextColor);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can create a new TextView and get the color from it.

```
TextView dummy = new TextView(getActivity());
myTextView.setTextColor(dummy.getTextColors());
```

Answer (score -2):

```
android:textColor=
```

Should do the trick, can also be invoked dynamic:

```
setTextColor(int)
```

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html for more on TextView

Comment: TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TextView);
tv.setTextColor(1);

Comment: hmh, sorry, text became black instead of the usual grey. :/